# How to auto increment update a column in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

How to auto increment update a column in a SQL Server table based on sorting other columns and restart the increment after value changes in other columns.

My table structure and data is like that:

```
Name   Class OldSrNo NewSrNo
----------------------------
aa     1      1        1
bb     1      2        2
aa     1      3        3
bb     2      4        1
cc     2      5        2
dd     2      6        3
aa     2      7        4
```

I want to update old sr no to look like NewSrNo

Comment: `"I want to update old sr no to look like NewSrNo"` - Can you just do this?:  `UPDATE MyTable SET OldSrNo = NewSrNo`

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking this,

```
Declare @t table (Name varchar(50),   Class int, OldSrNo int)
insert into @t values
('aa',     1,      1)       
,('bb',     1,      2)        
,('aa',     1,      3)        
,('bb',     2,      4)        
,('cc',     2,      5)        
,('dd',     2,      6)        
,('aa',     2,      7)  

select *, 
row_number()over(partition by class order by class)NewSrNo 
from @t
```